# How to switch back to main language after \foreignquote (csquotes, polyglossia, lualatex)?

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, csquotes

csquotes' `\foreignquote{language}{text}` does not seem to switch back all the language specific font features automatically. In my opinion the language specific changes should be applied only locally to the {text} (foreignquote's second argument) - am I wrong?

System Environment: Win 7 Pro 64-bit

TeX Environment: texlive 2014, latest updates (frozen)

TeX Procesor: lualatex

For details please run this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true,variant=german,spelling=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\noindent
German (kerning as expected):\\
\enquote{Hallo: Welt!}

\bigskip

\noindent
French (kerning as expected):\\
\foreignquote{french}{Bonjour: Tout le monde!}

\bigskip

\noindent
From now on unexpectedly french (at least kerning) is applied globally:\\
Hallo: Welt!

\bigskip

\noindent
Also here (note: although the quotation marks are fine, the kerning around the colon isn't):\\
\enquote{Hallo: Welt!}
\end{document}
```

Is this the intended behavior? What's the best way to switch back to the main language manually?

Comment: That's a bug in polyglossia and not related to csquotes. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186156/changing-language-back-and-forth-with-polyglossia.  With `\usepackage[french,ngerman]{babel}` it would work as expected (and use the much larger frenchb.ldf).

Comment: Oh, I just stumbled upon a similar [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186156/74259). Ulrike Fischer's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186174/74259) describes a workaround, that seem to be ok, until polyglossia is fixed. This question can be closed - sorry.

Comment: 47 secs to late. Thanks anyway! ;-) Regarding babel: But fontspec's documentation says: "The polyglossia package is recommended instead as a modern replacement for babel."?